# Webpack dev server attempts to connect to wrong url

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I'm having trouble with webpack every time i'm trying to give it a chance to be my friend! 
This time I'm trying to enable Hot Module Reloading with react-hot-loader, webpack & webpack-dev-server but it seems webpack-dev-server is trying to fetch a wrong url in browser.

This is the error from Chrome v50's console:

```
GET http://public/info?t=1464117419740   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

complete log:

```
abstract-xhr.js:132 GET http://public/info?t=1464117419740 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVEDAbstractXHRObject._start @ abstract-xhr.js:132(anonymous function) @ abstract-xhr.js:21
index.js:70 [WDS] Disconnected!sock.onclose @ index.js:70EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51(anonymous function) @ main.js:356
abstract-xhr.js:132 GET http://public/info?t=1464117421752 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVEDAbstractXHRObject._start @ abstract-xhr.js:132(anonymous function) @ abstract-xhr.js:21
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
{
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    // 'webpack-dev-server/client?path=http://localhost:3001/', // I have tested it with no luck
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3001/',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    './index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index.css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
  postcss: [
    values,
    cssnext
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot','babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on the webpack-dev-server/client entry point, and it's just the path in the querystring, no parameter name.

```
webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001
```

Comment: Setting output.publicPath to http://localhost:3001 worked for me